# Login page using Sessions and php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

in last days i were working at a script of php where that programme should make me do my job easly . generaly i'm using table '**users**' with attributs : **id, username, password, fullname, email, tel**

i have ***index.php*** as the main page of my script or as you can say my dashboard and ***login.php*** should be the form page of login where the client or me ^^ entre username and password to login and of cours ***logout.php*** for logout and ***session.php*** to check if the user is already loged-in also session.php the file who will be included in the header of all my other pages :)

soo i need somebody tell me how to programme a full system of login by seesion and mysql in php, like give me an exemple with the same names of those pages and table.

i hope my explaination is clear and if thiere is any question i'm here

Thanx a lot for help :D

Comment: so what's the problem on the code? and where is it anyway

Comment: the probleme that i need to make a login system using seesion and mysql in php

Comment: While most of us dont mind helping you, we are not here to write a program for you. We are not free, freelance developers. This is something you should attempt yourself, and THEN come here when you are stuck with a specific section, posting the part of the code that you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here, you cant simply ask somebody to tell you how to program a full system, at least spend some of your effort & time to try something first.

Maybe you can have a look at those example 1st.

- http://www.makeitsimple.co.in/PHP_loginexmp.php
- http://phppot.com/php/php-login-script-with-session/

Comment: Ahhhh... You beat me to the "try it yourself, first" statement.

Comment: Thankx a lot for your helping but i already resolved the problem about the effort and spending time i spend more than one week looking for something but no way ... every exemples are not working with me and that's why i ask you for help may be you give me some thing that i miss but in the end i didn't want you to make one as a plugin for me, all i need is just put in my programe and it running nooooo i was looking for something to compare it with my code and found exact where is the problem  



i'm so sorry for missunderstanding and thanx a lot for helping

Comment: hhhhhhh noooo i swear ... i were just looking for challenge my self that's all any way thanx a lot :)

Comment: @BâhâddôûMuhàmméd You can post your code in the question or you may use http://jsfiddle.net/ Basically we need more info from you to answer your question.